# How can I render multiple button in Column property?

Tags: asp.net, .net, razor, datatable, nopcommerce

I have a Entity DataTable.

```
   ColumnCollection = new List<ColumnProperty>
   {
             new ColumnProperty(nameof(ProductChapterMappingModel.Id))
       {
           Title = T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text,
           Width = "200",
           ClassName =  NopColumnClassDefaults.Button,
           Render = new RenderButtonsInlineEdit()
       }
   }
```

In the web view it is displaying like

[image]

This looks good but my requirement is to add another button called Details under the same column like:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
Render = new RenderCustom("ColumnBtns")
```

and then

```
function ColumnBtns(data, type, row, meta) {
        return 'Your HTML HERE'
       //and you can use the parameter row to reference the object represented by the   
       //row such as Id like that (row.Id)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        new ColumnProperty(nameof(Model.Command))
                                {
                                    Title = T("Plugins.Misc.Sales.Fields.Command").Text,
                                    Width = "100",
                                    ClassName =  NopColumnClassDefaults.Button,
                                    Render = new RenderCustom("renderColumnBtns")
                                }  

                        <script>

                            function renderColumnBtns(data, type, row, meta) {
                                var editlink = '@Url.Content("~/Admin/SalesCampaigns/Edit/")' + row.Id;
                                var detaillink = '@Url.Content("~/Admin/SalesCampaigns/Detail/")' + row.Id;
                                
                                return '<a class="btn btn-default"  href="' + editlink + '"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>@T("Plugins.Misc.Sales.Edit").Text</a>  <a class="btn btn-default"  href="' + detaillink + '"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>@T("Plugins.Misc.Sales.Detail").Text</a>';
                            }

                        </script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).